# Como passar uma variável como parâmetro para o "getElementById"

Tags: javascript, html5

Preciso colorir vários canvas, o code abaixo colore um deles

```
var canvas1 = document.getElementById("a1");
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
ctx1.fillStyle = cor; //aqui vai a cor html
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
```

Posso automatizar a cor através de um array tipo arrcor = [#F95201,#AB31AA,#E70078...], algo como:

```
ctx1.fillStyle = arrcor[i];
```

Mas eu preciso que cada cor dessa vá para um canvas diferente de acordo com o ID, algo como id="a1", id="a2", id="a3"... Por isso, preciso automatizar essa mudança, tentei passar uma variável dentro, tipo:

```
rolln = "a" + i;
var canvas1 = document.getElementById(rolln);
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
ctx1.fillStyle = cor; //aqui vai a cor html
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300); 

ou

var canvas1 = document.getElementById("a" + i);
var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
ctx1.fillStyle = cor; //aqui vai a cor html
ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
```

Mas não funciona, como eu faço para ele ir mudando o id, de acordo com o i (contador) dentro do laço já que o getElementById aceita somente uma string como parâmetro?

Comment: Deveria funcionar. Veja o exemplo no SO em ingles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068387/can-i-use-a-string-variable-in-document-getelementbyid . Seu canvas está na DOM? Pode ser isso...

Comment: dib, deveria funcionar já que `"a" + i` aqui é uma string tanto quanto `"a1"`. Veja se no console mostra erro, pq se `document.getElementById("a" + i)` não encontrar nada, dará um erro na linha `var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');`.

Comment: Exato, esse erro mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar a associação dentro de um array de objetos, como por exemplo:

```
var arrayCores = [
     {"nome_elemento": "a1", "cor": "#FFFFFF"}, 
     {"nome_elemento": "a2", "cor": "#AB31AA"}
];

for (var i in arrayCores){
   var canvas1 = document.getElementById(arrayCores[i]["nome_elemento"]);
   var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
   ctx1.fillStyle = arrayCores[i]["cor"];
   ctx1.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300); 
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu raciocínio, o ponto é que os id's não mudam, serão sempre a1, a2, a3..., mas as cores sim, elas serão repassadas por um cálculo.

Comment: Desculpe pela demora, mas no caso bastaria você fazer com que o arrayCores fosse populado depois de saber qual cor fosse para cada elemento